# In a large Perl hash, how do I extract a subset of particular keys?

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have a large hash and have a subset of keys that I want to extract the values for, without having to iterate over the hash looking for each key (as I think that will take too long).

I was wondering if I can use `grep` to grab a file with a subset of keys? For example, something along the lines of:

```
 my @value = grep { defined $hash{$_}{subsetofkeysfile} } ...;
```

Comment: just curious, how large is "large" ?

Comment: a million lines of data with up to 200 key/value pairs in each line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hash may not contain any keys from the subset, use a hash slice and grep:

```
my @values = grep defined, @hash{@keys};
```

You can omit the grep part if all keys are contained in the hash.

Comment: Are you saying that the @keys is a new array with just the subset?

Answer (score 7):

Use a hash slice:

```
my %hash = (foo => 1, bar => 2, fubb => 3);
my @subset_of_keys = qw(foo fubb);
my @subset_of_values = @hash{@subset_of_keys};  # (1, 3)
```

Two points of clarification. (1) You never need to iterate over a hash looking for particular keys or values. You simply feed the hash a key, and it returns the corresponding value -- or, in the case of hash slices, you supply a list of keys and get back a list of values. (2) There is a difference between `defined` and `exists`. If you're merely interested in whether a hash contains a specific key, `exists` is the correct test.

Comment: this seemed to be the most helpful answer in terms of understanding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)**,
 and try something like

```
foreach (@hash{qw[key1 key2]}) {
    # do something
    }
```